# Обособление "в зависимости"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли обособить обстоятельственный оборот в предложении: Масло(,) в зависимости от особенностей технологии изготовления(,) подразделяют на следующие виды...

Answer (score 1):

Обстоятельственный оборот обособляется факультативно (учитывается позиция оборота, его распространенность, структура предложения, стиль текста), но в текстах делового стиля его лучше расположить в начале предложения и не обособлять:

В зависимости от особенностей технологии изготовления масло подразделяют на следующие виды...

**В середине предложения этот оборот лучше обособить**, так как он является распространенным: Масло, в зависимости от особенностей технологии изготовления, подразделяют на следующие виды...

**Примеры с  обособлением:**

Заранее выберите место для фонтанчика и, **в зависимости от интерьера**, определите цвет чаши.

Руководствуясь данной нормой, прежде всего мы обратились к Общероссийскому классификатору "Отрасли народного хозяйства", в соответствии с которым организациям и предприятиям, **в зависимости от вида их деятельности**, присваивается определённый код.

Comment: Да, я знаю, что факультативно. Просто это выдержка из ГОСТа, запятых нет. А если обстоятельственный оборот находится между подлежащим и сказуемым, то рекомендуется его обособить. Вот теперь в раздумии. Структуру предложения нужно сохранить (будет ссылка на ГОСТ)

Comment: Тогда не надо обособлять, все-таки такие обстоятельства чаще обособляются в художественной речи, а в строго деловой лучше этого не делать.

Comment: >> *Просто это выдержка из ГОСТа, запятых нет... Вот теперь в раздумии...* Вот уж здесь раздумывать нечего. Сами же говорите: в ГОСТе нет запятых. О чем раздумывать?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос поднят. 
Поэтому отвечу, хотя ничего нового, видимо, не скажу.

Так, как вопрос поставлен, он имеет только один ответ. Обособление опционально. Здесь лучше обособить, иначе совсем плохо читается.

В отношении ГОСТа. Если для вас это так существенно, то об этом надо было написать в самом вопросе. Но тут ничего критичного. Если вы цитируете в кавычках, то надо указать, что пунктуация исправлена. Если же без кавычек, то это не обязательно. 
Впрочем, не будет большим грехом и оставить всё как есть в первоисточнике. Не потому, что это ГОСТ, а именно потому, что первоисточник.

> А если обстоятельственный оборот находится между подлежащим и
>   сказуемым

здесь нет подлежащего. *Масло* - объект в пассивной конструкции. Именно поэтому "де-юре" вполне можно не обособлять.